# Calculating TimeSpan with custom user given input in C#

Tags: c#

I want to create a program in C# for Calculating the timespan between two "custom user given" dates. I have written a code but it is not working. Please Help.

```
        string a, b, c, d, e, f;
        a = Console.ReadLine();
        b = Console.ReadLine();
        c = Console.ReadLine();
        d = Console.ReadLine();
        e = Console.ReadLine();
        f = Console.ReadLine();

        int g, h, i, j, k, l;
        g = int.Parse(a);
        h = int.Parse(b);
        i = int.Parse(c);
        j = int.Parse(d);
        k = int.Parse(e);
        l = int.Parse(f);
        DateTime FirstDate = DateTime.Parse("g/h/i");
        DateTime SecondDate = DateTime.Parse("j/k/l");

        TimeSpan Difference = SecondDate - FirstDate;

        Console.WriteLine(Difference.ToString());
        Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: What calendar uses letters in its dates? That was a joke. And a hint at your problem.

Comment: But I want to make any user input their custom dates and then the program should calculate the difference..

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think what you are trying to do is this:

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string month1 = Console.ReadLine();
        string day1 = Console.ReadLine();
        string year1 = Console.ReadLine();

        string month2 = Console.ReadLine();
        string day2 = Console.ReadLine();
        string year2 = Console.ReadLine();

        DateTime date1 = DateTime.Parse(string.Format("{0}/{1}/{2}", month1, day1, year1));
        DateTime date2 = DateTime.Parse(string.Format("{0}/{1}/{2}", month2, day2, year2));

        TimeSpan ts = date2 - date1;
        Console.WriteLine("There are {0} days(s) or {1} hour(s) or {2} minute(s) between those dates", ts.TotalDays, ts.TotalHours, ts.TotalMinutes );
    }
}
```

You can see a [live action fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/6PQmIm) of this program!

This assumes that you are reading in your dates based on Month, Day, then Year. If you need a different format, then you will need to rearrange some things, but this should give you the general idea.

As a side note, programmers everywhere would appreciate it if your programs had descriptive variable names. It is bad practice to call variables `a` or `b` or `c`. That kind of thing in a production environment program would get your butt kicked fast by other programmers!

EDIT:

Since you are entering in a day/month/year format, use this instead:

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string day1 = Console.ReadLine();
        string month1 = Console.ReadLine();
        string year1 = Console.ReadLine();

        string day2 = Console.ReadLine();
        string month2 = Console.ReadLine();
        string year2 = Console.ReadLine();

        DateTime date1 = DateTime.Parse(string.Format("{0}/{1}/{2}", month1, day1, year1));
        DateTime date2 = DateTime.Parse(string.Format("{0}/{1}/{2}", month2, day2, year2));

        TimeSpan ts = date2 - date1;
        Console.WriteLine("There are {0} days(s) or {1} hour(s) or {2} minute(s) between those dates", ts.TotalDays, ts.TotalHours, ts.TotalMinutes );
    }
}
```

Comment: I am getting an error on the DateTime.Parse Line. The error says "An unhandled exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."

Comment: And Also When i just copied and paste your program it shows the same error again..

Comment: @Prajjwal -- What numbers are you entering in your input?

Comment: OK I have given 6 inputs "20, 08, 1997, 20, 08, 2014" in their respective orders.

Comment: Shouldn't I Change the string format into integer format for dates??

Comment: @Prajjwal -- The problem was because you were entering your dates in a day/month/year format instead of a month/day/year. Look at my updated answer.

Comment: concat + parse is fragile, and exposed to different locales. I'll post a different answer with my solution.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand what you tried to do there, but look at this:

```
DateTime dt1 = new DateTime(2014,10,10,17,10,00); // 2014-10-10 17:10.00
DateTime dt2 = new DateTime(2014,10,10,13,05,00); // 2014-10-10 13:05.00
var difference = dt1.Subtract(dt2); // 04:05.00
```

Comment: I want to make any user input their custom dates and then the program should calculate the difference.. –

Comment: Ok, all you need to do now is change the static dates into inputted dates.

Comment: Thats where i am having the problem. Please can you elaborate the method for using inputted dates..

Answer (score 0):

This will work in case both are in Datetime format

```
(SecondDate - FirstDate).TotalDays
//return float
```

or

```
(SecondDate - FirstDate).Days
//returns int
```

Answer (score 0):

If you already force the user to enter separate day/month/year, you shouldn't concat them into a single string and then `DateTime.Parse` them - you're exposing yourself to all kinds of date format issues. Instead, use them separately:

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string day1 = Console.ReadLine();
        string month1 = Console.ReadLine();
        string year1 = Console.ReadLine();

        string day2 = Console.ReadLine();
        string month2 = Console.ReadLine();
        string year2 = Console.ReadLine();

        DateTime date1 = new DateTime(year: int.Parse(year1), month: int.Parse(month1), day: int.Parse(day1));
        DateTime date2 = new DateTime(year: int.Parse(year2), month: int.Parse(month2), day: int.Parse(day2));

        TimeSpan ts = date2 - date1;
        Console.WriteLine("There are {0} days(s) or {1} hour(s) or {2} minute(s) between those dates", ts.TotalDays, ts.TotalHours, ts.TotalMinutes );
    }
}
```

Or, you can get your user to enter fully-formed dates, and parse those:

```
(...)
        string date1Str = Console.ReadLine();
        string date1Str = Console.ReadLine();

        DateTime date1 = DateTime.Parse(date1Str);
        DateTime date2 = DateTime.Parse(date2Str);
(...)
```